# Why doesn't Stack Overflow have a domain for FAQs?

Tags: support

I was roaming around Stack Overflow, but I did not find any direct link for a FAQ. Can any one suggest how to get the FAQ part on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Top right corner in screen there is a drop down help in which there is link for help center.

Answer (score 8):

There is a [faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/faq?sort=votes) tag on Meta Stack Exchange.

Questions tagged with this tag are considered to be the FAQ for the entire network or sites, including Stack Overflow.